# Executing <script> in innerHTML angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have not typical question. How can i execute script in innerHtml. I got a string with given script like this below.

```
<strong>asdasd</strong><br>
<p>asdasd</p>
<script>alert('aa')</script>
```

And try to inject it to my component like this.

```
<div [innerHTML]="customScript"></div>
```

My problem is  doesn't show alert. How can I force innerHTML to executing my script?

`customScript` isn't hardcoded anywhere. It's just a string that comes from back-end. It can contains any tag like html, body, div, script (yes! script needs to be there) and need to make this string running in my component as normal html/script code.

Comment: @FernandoValderramaGuayán Since this is angular, where the creation/modification/deletion of components can easily be dynamic, the change could easily not be associated with a page load.

Comment: You need to pass it through the sanitizer

Comment: Where is that customScript html coming from? It's generally not a good practice to do what you are trying to do. You would want to do that in a more "native" Angular way. If that `customScript` is hardcoded, you could just call the alert in a lifecycle method.

Comment: @ulmas customScript isn't hardcoded anywhere. It's just a string that comes from back-end. It can contains any tag like html, body, div, script (yes! script needs to be there) and need to make this string running in my component as normal html/script code.

Comment: Short answer: don't. You're using angular: trigger JS that injects a `<script>` into `document.head`. Also, never use `alert`. We've had the [console API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) since 2010, use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to get all contents of `<script/>`, then use `eval()` to run it.

Comment: What do you mean by ElementRef? How did you solve it?